# EF Core: Both eager loading and lazy loading fail (potential bug)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using the latest version of EF Core, and it fails loading navigational properties as it is supposed to. 
Assuming the following entity classes

```
public partial class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
        Inventories = new HashSet<Inventories>();
    }

    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Inventories> Inventories { get; set; }
}
public partial class Inventories
{
    public Inventories()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
    }

    public string InventoryId { get; set; }
    ..
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
}
```

The followings fails attaching the `Category` entity to the query:

```
var query = Db.Set<Inventories>();
//query.FirstOrDefault().Category is Null
query.Include(x=> x.Category);
//query.FirstOrDefault().Category is Null
query.Include("Category");
//query.FirstOrDefault().Category is Null
```

However if I do this both Lazy and Eager loading work:

```
var query = Db.Set<Categories>();
var query2 = Db.Set<Inventories>();
//query2.FirstOrDefault().Category Has Value
```

Comment: What do you mean by " latest version of EF Core"? From nightly builds or something? And if it's a potential bug, why posting it here instead of their GitHub?

Comment: Also how about `query = query.Include(x=> x.Category);`, i.e.. using the result of the `Include`? Currently it's like `query.Where(...)` which does nothing.

Comment: @IvanStoev: same, you have to load both tables, although the two queries may have nothing to with each other so force them to load, else it never works. In ASP.Net core, have you notice the alpha versions?? I mean this one "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-alpha1-22398",

Comment: Can you clarify the EF Core version? Because it works in the latest **released** version of EF Core (1.0.1)

Comment: @IvanStoev: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-alpha1-22398",

Comment: Yes - bugs in pre-release code should be posted as an issue on the relevant Github repo, not as Q&A questions on SO.